# Unify different date format

Tags: regex

I have a list of dates with mixed date format of:

```
mm/dd/yyyy
yyyy/mm/dd
dd/mm/yy
d/m/yy
```

In one file. Is there an approach that to use regex to match them and update to the same format: `yyyy-mm-dd`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: It would be possible with about 6 replaces but not very efficient. Better split each line by /, analyze and return the correct format.

Comment: This really does not sounds like a good regex task. You'd could chain replacement to converge reduce number of formats and reach the desired one and to "leap" from `yy` to `yyyy`.

Comment: which langauage ? regex engines differs depending on languages, and it may be [possible](https://regex101.com/r/e1HDkn/1) or not, using tricks but not with one unique standard regex